# Disable portrait mode on tablet using CSS

Tags: css, orientation, tablet

I have created a website that should only be viewed in Landscape mode on tablets.

Using CSS, is there a way to hide the website and display an image / text if the user loads the website in Portrait mode?

Thank you in advance for your help,
ZeBobo

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use CSS Media queries.

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation)

Code is copied from MDN docs. This explains on how to use the landscape and portrait orientations.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  background: yellow;
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Box 1</div>
<div>Box 2</div>
<div>Box 3</div>
```

Be careful while using this. There's no actual compatibility list provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { … }
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

Inside you can specify what to show, i.e. the text information on how to view the page.

Comment: Many thanks for getting back to me. Is there a way I can display an image using CSS?